# Как создать отдельный поток с другого класса?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Возникла проблема при создании отдельного потока.
Вызываю с основного метода:

```
namespace Program
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Patch.UI.Window = this;
            Patch.Starter();
        }
       ...
```

Patch.starter:

```
namespace Program
{
    class Patch
    {
        public static MainWindow Window = null;

        public static void Starter()
        {
            Patch startPatch = new Patch();
            System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(startPatch.Start);
            t.Start();
        }
        ...
```

Не знаю правильно ли делаю, но в итоге нужно, чтобы метод Patch.Start() вызвался в отдельном потоке, при открытии приложения.

Сейчас выдается ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Comment: Вы пятаетесь работать с объектами  GUI из соседнего потока, вот вам и ошибка...

Comment: 1) Используйте пул потоков, если вам явно не обязателен отдкльный поток 2) К UI элементам можно иметь доступ только из того потока, в котором они были созданы.

Comment: Дело в том, что раньше я запускал без потока, так:

```
 private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Patch.Start();
        }
```

Но после того, как я убрал стандартное окно windows(сделал своё), то это событие не срабатывает. Поэтому нужно как-то запустить эту функцию после открытия приложения. Можно более подробнее получить ответ?

Comment: @ヒミコ Можно поподробнее, как мне лучше сделать тогда?
Если я вызываю этот метод без отдельного потока, то ошибки нет

Comment: То у вас с потоком проблема, то с кастомным окном. Вы определитесь и добавьте нужную информацию в вопрос. В текущем виде не ясна ваша проблема.

Comment: Мне нужно любым способом вызвать метод Patch.Start() после открытия окна.

Comment: Вызывайте его на window_loaded

Comment: @tym32167 Проблема в том, что когда я вызываю так:
```public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Patch.UI.Window = this;
            Patch startPatch = new Patch();
            startPatch.Start();
        }```
То приложение открывается долго, т.к. в методе Start() стоит проверка подключения к веб-сайту. Необходимо открыть в отдельном потоке метод  Start()

Comment: `private void Window_loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            MessageBox.Show("123");
            Patch startPatch = new Patch();
            startPatch.Start();
        }`

Тоже не срабатывает данный метод.

Comment: Патоки уже очень давно не используются так напрямую, ибо достаточно простейших `async/await` почти для всех задач (ваша не исключение). По поводу работы с контролами из другого потока - это WPF, тут принято работать с привязанными свойствами, а не контролами! Научитесь делать привязки, ну а так - это дубликат...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ посмотрел "дубликат вопроса" - решить свой вопрос не получилось.

Comment: У вас есть какой то метод, который хз что делает. У вас какое то кастомное окно, кода которого Вы тоже не показали. Непонятно, какого ответа вы ожидаете с таким вопросом. Вас никто тут не сможет помочь без подробностей с вашей стороны. И не надо код в комментарии кидать, добавляйте код в вопрос.

Comment: Какой именно метод необходимо показать, чтобы вопрос был понятен вам?

Comment: Покажите метод Start, покажите строчку, в которой возникает исключение, расскажите, зачем вам другой поток? Можете показать хоть оба класса целиком в вопросе. Чем больше кода - тем понятнее.

Answer (score 0):

Если я верно понял это WPF ?
Не совсем понял, почему у вас отвалились события, как вы реализовали свое окно ?
Пробовали ли вы событие Loaded ?
Если вам нужно обратится к UI из другого потока, это можно обернуть в

```
 public void Start(){

   //Какой-то тяжелый код 

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{
           //работа с UI
          });
   }
```

Ну и можно ваш костыль, заменить на другой костыль - запустить например таймер с однократным срабатыванием(есть потокобезопасные таймеры)
Но опять же эток костыль не лучше вашего... я бы посоветовал почиать про Task + async await на этом можно реализовать более удобное и красиво решение

Comment: Имеете в виду вызвать метод внутри данной конструкции?
`Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                Patch startPatch = new Patch();
                startPatch.Start();
            });` Вот так открывается также, как и без данной конструкции, приложение ждет выполнения Start().

Comment: @Qiveq Признаться по вашему коду мало что понятно. Я имел в виду можно вызвать поток, внутри него выполнить "тяжелый" код, а потом(в этом же потоке) выполнить код взаимодействующий с UI, но обернуть именно его в Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke  Но на будущее рекомендую изучить Task + async, на таком коде вы далеко не уедете )))

Comment: @Qiveq доработал пример, это типа ваш метод выполняющийся в потоке

Comment: Как бы я не пытался сделать в отдельный поток выполнение Start(), выдается ошибка, скриншот которой в вопросе.

Comment: Вы пытались ответить на не конкретизированный вопрос, на который невозможно дать ответ, можно только гадать. Не надо так. Гадания на StackOverflow не приветствуются.